# iTunes not playing without audio devices connected to audio port

Tags: windows-7, video, audio, itunes

I am trying to use iTunes to loop through a playlist of videos – I do not need any audio output for these videos.

If I unplug the audio device (headphones, speakers, etc.) from the audio jack on the back of the computer, iTunes freezes and Windows shows me some errors about no audio devices being detected.

Is there a way to make iTunes play without an audio device connected to the jack?
I'm assuming this is a Windows issue because I don't think that the iTunes app would check for a connected audio device before playing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a fake audio driver somewhere that basically allows iTunes to play without any audio devices on the computer, this make sure that iTunes keeps playing and solves the problem. You can probably use any audio driver that fakes audio devices for this purpose...